# python -m behind a corporate proxy

Tags: python, proxy

I have all my proxy environment variable set in my `.bashrc` (HTTP_PROXY, HTTPS_PROXY and their lower case variants), and all required hosts have been added to the proxy server as exceptions, including `github.com`, but when I issue `python -m spacy download en` I get:

```
Collecting en_core_web_sm==2.1.0 from https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.1.0/en_core_web_sm-2.1.0.tar.gz#egg=en_core_web_sm==2.1.0
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden',))': /84940268/85ec3200-48aa-11e9-9878-337412e36828?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A%2F20190513%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20190513T164037Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=27c4af0fcb6043dba9efa4f7f4be7aced7af7fba51208a31e9737b59403e3e99&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3Den_core_web_sm-2.1.0.tar.gz&response-content-type=application%2Foctet-stream
```

etc.

Note: `git clone` works fine as does `pip install`, etc.

Not sure why installing through `python -m` would be problematic. Nothing in any searches I've done have env variable config information to use `python -m`, so not sure what the deal is?

Comment: I’m behind my company firewall as well and neither `pip install` nor `python -m` works. So I download everything to local and use `pip install -e`.

Comment: That's encouraging!

Comment: Have you tried using `python -m spacy download en --trusted-host github.com`? `spacy` takes similar flags to `pip`

Comment: Alternatively, have you tried to manually `pip install https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.1.0/en_core_web_sm-2.1.0.tar.gz`?

Comment: Ha! Neither seem to work. But, `pip` and `git clone` on their own are fine.

Comment: I think I will just do the download of the `tar.gz` and `scp` it over. Uggh!

Comment: Issue ended up being that the github page in question redirects to `s3.amazonaws`, which is black listed at our corporate proxy.

Comment: Had to use the following to get the model installed: `python -m spacy download en -e en_core_web_sm-2.1.0` (`en_core_web_sm-2.1.0` was the untarred directory).